# What's the best solution for embedding video into an ASP.NET website?

Tags: asp.net, video, embedded-video

Ok first off, I know nothing about video player technologies so any help whatsoever is appreciated. I'm sorry if this is vague but I'm hoping that with feedback I can get more specific. Basically I'm trying to figure out what options there are for embedding video player technology into an ASP.NET website and what are the pros and cons of each.

Right now I know there are sites like Vimeo where you can upload videos and link them to your website but this solution doesn't seem very customizable. You can also embed flash players into a website without the need to have a Vimeo account but I don't want to convert every video to flash and that would be a maintenance problem later. If I host the video on the server it will slow things down and potentially be a problem too. There are a lot of options and tradeoffs so I just wanted to get some feedback from people who have dealt with this sort of thing.

If you have implemented embedded video content in an ASP.NET page before, what solution did you choose and how did things turn out?

**EDIT**
The videos aren't really a core part of the website and they won't need to be dynamically submitted or anything. I would have the videos during development and I'm just wondering what the best overall solution would be for any client that wants a simple video on their website.

Comment: What are the purpose of the videos? Are videos a core component of your web site? Are they just used for introductions or tutorials? Are they user-submitted? etc...

Comment: I'm looking for a general solution that would work for any client that wants video content on their website, but it would be something simple. There are lots of options out there and I'm trying to pinpoint the best ones.

Comment: I'm thinking that you're going to end up offering the user more than one version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just happened to come across this while tinkering with the new ASP.Net MVC3 with the Razor view engine.

You can quickly embed videos using Razor's video helper method.

Syntax:

Flash:

```
@*Video.Flash(filename [, width, height])*@
@Video.Flash("test.swf", "100", "100")
```

Media Player:

```
@*Video.MediaPlayer(filename [, width, height])*@
@Video.MediaPlayer("test.wmv", "100", "100")
```

Silverlight video:

```
@*Video.Silverlight(filename, width, height)*@
@Video.Silverlight("test.xap", "100", "100")
```

Comment: We haven't really done much with ASP.NET MVC or the Razor view engine, but this is cool, I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: Yea Razor is pretty slick I have been drilling through all the info at http://asp.net/mvc.